# Appending variable list to list in Python

Tags: python

Today, we were asked to write a Python file which asks the user to input a positive integer and prints the list:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3],..., [1, 2, 3,..., n]]
```

Here's my code:

```
A=[]
n=int(input("Input a positive integer:"))
if n>0: A=[[1]]
B=[1]
for i in range(2,n+1):
   B+=[i]
   A+=[B]
print(A)
```

This seemed like it would work. But instead of the result it gives me:

```
[[1], [1, 2, 3,..., n], [1, 2, 3,..., n],..., [1, 2, 3,..., n]]
```

It seems to replace the "B"s which were appended to A with the new "B".
I really don't understand why it does that. Can anybody here explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `A+=B` you are creating a reference to the mutable object `B`. The `+=` operation creates a reference, not a copy. Try changing this to `A+=B[:]` -- this is an easy shorthand for copying the contents of a list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this really clarified things. Can you tell me why lists act like this? Why aren't they the same as integers or strings?

Comment: In most languages) identifiers ("variables") are containers that hold values; in Python they ("identifiers") are names that point to objects. If two names point to one object, they are essentially aliases. The difference with strings & ints is, they are immutable objects. When you say `x=newvalue` for a mutable object (like a list) that list (object) is updated; but for an immutable object (like an int) a new object is created and replaces the prior one. Great (deeper) explanation here: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: Thanks for answering. But that's not what I wanted to know. I was asking why the people making Python made it do that. It just seems weird to me for that distinction between lists and integers or strings to be there for no reason.

Comment: Good question -- ask it differently -- in Python why are some types immutable and others not?  There are a few reasons: (1) immutable objects are inherently thread-safe; (2) immutable objects can be interned, which saves memory & time; (3) numbers and strings are the most common choice for dictionary keys, and keys must be immutable.  The best explanation I've heard is that with a mutable object, you can change it's value without changing it's identity -- but with an immutable object, value = identity.  I.e. 4 is 4, how could that ever change? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because what you insert to A is a **reference** to B, you are not creating n separate lists.
This means that when you are modifying B you modify all it's references, i.e. all the entries in the list A (except for the first that is a separate list).

The following code works:

```
n=int(input("Input a positive integer:"))
A=[range(1, i+1) for i in range(2, n+1)]
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (in Python 3, for range/xrange considerations):

```
A = []
n = int(input("Input a positive integer: "))
for i in map(lambda s: range(1, s+1), range(1, n+1)):
    A.append(list(i))
```

Maybe concepts like `map` and lambdas are too advanced for your class, but just in case.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
A=[]
n=int(input("Input a positive integer:"))
if n>0:
    A = [[1]]

i = 2

while i <= n:
    B = range(1,i+1)
    A.append(B)
    i = i+1
print(A)
```

Answer (score -1):

You've accidentally learned the difference between a copy and a deep copy.

Internally your list reads [1, B, B, B.....B].

Basically A+=[B] inserts a reference to B, not the value of B.

One solution is:

import deepcopy #at the top of your code

A+=[deepcopy.deepcopy(B)] #disclaimer: I am doing this from memory

Another solution is A+=[A[-1]+[i]] #get rid of the variable B entirely

This works because the value A[-1]+[i] is not referenced by any other variable.

I'm sure the reason your original code fails will be covered more in depth later on in your class. If you want you can ignore it for now as a funny little "bug".

Comment: Not accurate. His original code wasn't doing any kind of copy (neither shallow nor deep). A reference is not a copy. And a shallow copy will solve his problem.